# Horizontal scrollbar height issue with IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, scrollbar

I have an element which looks like this at the top of my website:

```
#top { position:fixed;top:0;left:0;margin:0;padding:0;height:60px;width:100%; }
```

I have an other element which looks like this at the bottom :

```
#footer { margin:0;padding:0;position:fixed;height:60px;bottom:0;left:0;width:100%; }
```

Between these two elements, I have finally a #main element in the middle like this :

```
#main { margin:0;padding:0;position:absolute;top:60px;left:0;bottom:60px;width:3000px; }
```

Everything is OK with Chrome / Firefox / Safari but not with IE9. It looks like the height of the horizontal scrollbar (which is about 15px) is counted within the height of the #main element. So the 15px height area at the bottom of the #main element is hidden behind the #footer element.

Could you please help me ?

Edit : **here is an example of the issue...**

http://statosphere.fr/stackoverflow/test.php

With Chrome and Firefox, you can see the entire yellow square (30x30px). But with IE9, you can't see the bottom of the yellow square, hidden behind the red footer.

Comment: OK sorry, you're right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does seem to be an IE9-specific problem with the scrollbar.

Try wrapping it in a `<div>` that contains the `width` like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="element"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontainer{
  width:3000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly with every browser now. :)